# Ajax can't reach success field

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

I'm having some trouble with my servlet and ajax.  Here's the servlet code:

```
@GetMapping(value="/servlet/getImage", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RequestMapping(value = "/servlet/getImage", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
String getImage() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("/Test.png");
    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] fileContent = null;
    try{
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
        baos.flush();
        fileContent = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
}
```

In the above code I am simply grabbing an image from a folder and converting to a byte array and sending as a base64 through the servlet.

Now where it gets weird is this, here's my AJAX code:

```
function showImage() {

$.ajax ({
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer' + auth,
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        'DataType' : 'json'
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/getImage',
    success: function(result)
    {
       console.log("we work!");
       $("#content").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + result);

    }
  });
}
```

When I run this, in my browser I get code 200 (success) - however, I don't get the console log of "we worked!".  So how is it that it's giving a code of 200 which is success but it fails to enter the success part of the ajax?  I couldn't find anything on google about this so you're my last hope.

Thank you so much!

Comment: you are not producing `APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` but a base64 encoded string which is not valid json. Also using both `GetMapping` and `RequestMapping` is redundant, pick one.

Comment: I see, I read base64 could be sent as json.  If you don't mind, what MediaType would you recommend I replace that with?  Thank you Marco!  (and I'll be sure to remove the redundancy, my apologies.)

Comment: base64 encoded strings can definitely be embedded inside json objects, but that is not what you are doing. A base64 string is just text so I think TEXT_PLAIN is more appropriate.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi - Thank you so much!  It works now.  I really appreciate you taking the time and helping me.